# Discord.py reactions counting

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted, to make giveaway command. I know how to do this, but there's one problem, i don't know how to make my bot count reactions. I maked a command, bot sends message, adds reactions, sleep x time, and then it must to count reactions and choose winner. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. send message
2. wait x seconds
3. fetch the message again
4. count the total reactions
5. choose a random reaction
6. choose a random user

```py
# 1
message = await ctx.send('Waiting x seconds')
# 2
await asyncio.sleep(x)
# 3
message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
# 4
total_count = 0
for r in message.reactions:
    total_count += r.count
# 5
reaction = random.choice(message.reactions)
# 6
members = await reaction.users().flatten()
winner = random.choice(members)
```