# How do I check which reaction inthe message is higher in Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So basicly, I'm creating a command that let you vote for something and after 5 min it will check which is higher.

But the problem is I don't know how to do that.

Here is my code so far:

```
@client.command()
async def strongy_boi(ctx, boi):
  if boi == "copper-golem-allay":
    mess = await ctx.send(":heart: = copper golem :blue_heart: = allay")
    await mess.add_reaction('❤️')
    await mess.add_reaction('')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    #do code that check which is higher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is to access the message reactions through [`discord.Message.reactions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message%20reactions#discord.Message.reactions) and iterate through them, checking the [`discord.Reaction.count`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=reaction%20count#discord.Reaction.count) and comparing with the current highest. To check for reactions, however, a message needs to be cached, which can be done through [`await fetch_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message). Do view the revised code and further explanations below.

```py
@client.command()
async def strongy_boi(ctx, boi):
  if boi == "copper-golem-allay":
    mess = await ctx.send("❤️ = copper golem  = allay")
    await mess.add_reaction('❤️')
    await mess.add_reaction('')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

    # new code starts here #

    msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(mess.id) # 'Cache' the message
    # create variables to save the highest reactions
    highest_reaction = ""
    highest_reaction_number = 0

    # msg.reactions format: 
    # [<Reaction emoji='❤️' me=True count=2>, <Reaction emoji='' me=True count=1>]

    for reaction in msg.reactions: # iterate through every reaction in the message
      if (reaction.count-1) > highest_reaction_number:
        # (reaction.count-1) discounts the bot's reaction
        highest_reaction = reaction.emoji
        highest_reaction_count = reaction.count-1

    await ctx.send(f"{highest_reaction} wins with {highest_reaction_count} votes!")
```

[image: Working image]

**Other Links**:

- [Count reactions on a message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58734452/discord-py-count-reactions-on-a-message) - Stackoverflow
- [How do I count reactions on a message in discord py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867989/how-do-i-count-reactions-on-a-message-in-discord-py) - Stackoverflow
- [Reactions counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65073089/discord-py-reactions-counting) - Stackoverflow
- [Get a List of Reactions on a Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62965493/get-a-list-of-reactions-on-a-message-discord-py) - Stackoverflow